# Why is it a "lost update" in the Read Committed Transactions example of Oracle documentation?

Tags: oracle, transactions, isolation, read-committed

In the book "*Oracle Database Concepts*", Oracle gives an example to explain `Read Committed Isolation Level`.

In the example, transaction 1 updates row 1, then transaction 2 updates the same row before transaction 1 commits. So, transaction 2 waits until transaction 1 commits. Then transaction 1 commits. Transaction 2 commits after that. Of course, after transaction 2 commits, update of row 1 by transaction 1 is overridden by transaction 2.

It consider this situation as a `lost update`. But in my view, it should not be a "lost update" since transaction 1 has committed. Lost update is considered in one single transaction. The schedule is even equal to a serializable schedule regardless of read operations.

The example is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17633/consist.htm#CNCPT1319), or more specifically, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17633/consist.htm#CNCPT89216).

In Oracle's glossary, lost update is -

> A data integrity problem in which one writer of data overwrites the changes of a different writer modifying the same data.

So, what do you think of this? Is it a "lost update" and if so, could this kind of lost update be avoided by concurrency control of database?

Any comments and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is considered a "lost update" because Session 2 overwrote the change that Session 1 had made without being aware that it was doing so.  As far as Session 2 is concerned it read the 'Banda' row with a salary of 6200 and updated it to 6300 - it never saw Session 1's update to 7000.

As that documentation says: "devising a strategy to handle lost updates is an important part of application development" - i.e. it is not part of the in-built data concurrency functionality of the DBMS.  Within a transaction this can be done by using `select for update` to attempt to lock the row. In this example, Session 2's select of the 'Banda' row would have been blocked if it had done this.  Once session 1 had committed, session 2 would get the lock **and** would see the new salary.  In a stateless environment like a web application [optimistic locking](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:5771117722373) is used to achieve this.